# What is the space between the sections in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I've got this HTML structure:

```
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <div id="panels">
        <section id="sect0" name="lvl0">
            <div id="divLvel0" class="level zero">
                <h2>top<nav><ul><li><a href="#sect1">Languages</a></li><li><a href="#sect2">Proficiency</a></li><li><a href="#sect3">Milestones</a></li><li><a href="#sect4">Details</a></li></ul></nav></h2>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="sect1" name="lvl1">
            <div id="divLvel1" class="level one">
                <div id="panel_lvl1">
                    <h2>Languages</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="sect2" name="lvl2">
        </section>
        <section id="sect3" name="lvl3">
            <div id="divLvel3" class="level three">
                <div id="panel_lvl3">
                    <h2>Milestones</h2>
                    <div id="chart3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="sect4" name="lvl4">
            <div id="divLvel4" class="level four">
                <div id="panel_lvl4">
                    <h2>Details</h2>
                    <div id="chart4">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/Lkdo5xv3/2/

Every section touch each other directly, i.e. there is no additional element in between the sections. But somehow you can see a gap (the green background color) between each section.

I already set the padding and the margin of the body to zero. Also I replaced the sections with DIVs. But the gap is still there.

How do I get rid of the gap and make each section touch other without a gap between them?

Comment: Set the padding on the green container to 0

Comment: dear @thadeuszlay : please upvote / accept the answer you find most fitting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

reset padding and margin for all objects at the start of your style

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

after that you can set padding and margin as you want for each object

Comment: true. Is this the default padding and margin that is set for every HTML and that I have to reset to 0?

Comment: That's definitely a bad practice. Resetting ALL margins and ALL paddings of ALL elements to 0 is going to make you have to re-write a lot of code that would be just there for you in the browser stylesheets. Look at my answer about using a Normalizer.

Comment: you can use `* {padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}` to reset all of the elements' margins and paddings.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the green background is coming from. What you are seeing is the `body` element. Imagine there are 'holes' in your layout through which you see what's behind.

[image: where the green color is coming from]

I advise you to always use a [CSS Normalizer](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in order to harmonize and set reasonable defaults for your elements.

In your example, you need to add:

```
h2 { margin: 0; padding: 0}
body { margin: 0; }
```

as well as remove the padding of sections. Here is the working snippet:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.zero,
.one,
.two,
.three,
.four {
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.outer-box {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.zero {
  background: red;
}
.one {
  background: LightSeaGreen;
}
.two {
  background: LightGreen;
}
.three {
  background: HotPink;
}
.four {
  background: LightSteelBlue;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <div id="panels">
    <section id="sect0" name="lvl0">
      <div id="divLvel0" class="level zero">
        <h2>top<nav><ul><li><a href="#sect1">Languages</a></li><li><a href="#sect2">Proficiency</a></li><li><a href="#sect3">Milestones</a></li><li><a href="#sect4">Details</a></li></ul></nav></h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sect1" class="outer-box" name="lvl1">
      <div id="divLvel1" class="level one">
        <div id="panel_lvl1">
          <h2>Languages</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sect3" class="outer-box" name="lvl3">
      <div id="divLvel3" class="level three">
        <div id="panel_lvl3">
          <h2>Milestones</h2>
          <div id="chart3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sect4" class="outer-box" name="lvl4">
      <div id="divLvel4" class="level four">
        <div id="panel_lvl4">
          <h2>Details</h2>
          <div id="chart4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want the blue background of the sections to be seen though. The gap within the sections (the blue background) should remain. The gap between the sections (the green background) should be removed. I'll look at your solution when I get home. :)

Comment: I think it's important to understand the basic principles of margin/padding resets and when to use what. If you need blue empty boxes, make an element with a common class and give it a `background-color: blue` and a `height: 100px` (for example). Place the element everywhere you need it.

Comment: Hmm... ok. I'll consider what you said. But please tell me, what is the the gap (the green one) is there? I never specified it.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you where the green color is coming from/why is it's there. Please also reconsider your selected answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect in my comment, your body had a margin and that is why you had the space around the elements.

I'm assuming you're using a browser with a similar rendering engine, and as such they sometimes have default styles that may not show up. Seems like it was the case here, just set the margin-bottom on all elements to 0 or simply just reset margins and padding on all elements and add them when you need.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: green;
}
.zero,
.one,
.two,
.three,
.four {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 1000px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.zero,
.sel:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
.one,
.sel:nth-child(2) {
  background: LightSeaGreen;
}
.two,
.sel:nth-child(3) {
  background: LightGreen;
}
.three,
.sel:nth-child(4) {
  background: HotPink;
}
.four,
.sel:nth-child(5) {
  background: LightSteelBlue;
}
#sect0,
#sect1,
#sect2,
#sect3,
#sect4 {
  /* The image used */
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <div id="panels">
    <section id="sect0" name="lvl0">
      <div id="divLvel0" class="level zero">
        <h2>top<nav><ul><li><a href="#sect1">Languages</a></li><li><a href="#sect2">Proficiency</a></li><li><a href="#sect3">Milestones</a></li><li><a href="#sect4">Details</a></li></ul></nav></h2>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sect1" name="lvl1">
      <div id="divLvel1" class="level one">
        <div id="panel_lvl1">
          <h2>Languages</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sect2" name="lvl2">
    </section>
    <section id="sect3" name="lvl3">
      <div id="divLvel3" class="level three">
        <div id="panel_lvl3">
          <h2>Milestones</h2>
          <div id="chart3">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="sect4" name="lvl4">
      <div id="divLvel4" class="level four">
        <div id="panel_lvl4">
          <h2>Details</h2>
          <div id="chart4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: nope. As you can see there is still a green background visible, e.g. below the red section.

Comment: the easiest way to see what styles are causing issues is to right click the element and click 'inspect', if you click on 'computed' it will show you all the dimensions for margins and paddings your browser is using.

Comment: ...yeah, I know. But still I can't find what's responsible for the gap.

Answer (score -1):

Add padding and margin 0. In addition change your html to this:

```
<section></section><!--
--><section></section>
```

Or in one line:

```
<section></section><section></section>
```

Comment: Sorry Wim, whitespace only matters if the elements are set to display: inline-block, which is not the case here.